# scrape href of each product from website using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup to scrape the href of each product in this webpage: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=digital+camera. These hrefs end up with "keywords=digital+camera"
Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=digital+camera"
keyword = "keywords=digital+camera"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    href = link.get('href')
    if href is None:
        continue
    elif keyword in href:  
        print href
```

I got nothing back from above script, is there anything I can do to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: have you tried printing all of the hrefs and "ctrl+f"ing to see that you are actually getting what you think you are getting? I just printed `[x.get("href") for x in soup.find_all('a')]` and didnt get anything that had the string `"keywords=digital+camera"` in it

Comment: @TehTris yes, I tried. I didn't get anything with keyword in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon is detecting the user-agent ("the name of your browser") and changing the content based on that value. If you add a user-agent to the request, you'll get the strings with "keyword=digital+camera" added to them. Otherwise, you don't.

```
url ="http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=digital+camera"
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.find_all('a')
for l in links:
    href = l.get('href')
    title = l.get('title', '')
    if 'Sony W800/B 20.1 MP Digital' in title:
        print(href)  # prints: http://www.amazon.com/Sony-W800-Digital-Camera-Black/dp/B00I8BIBCW/ref=sr_1_2/183-0842534-8993425?s=photo&ie=UTF8&qid=1421400650&sr=1-2&keywords=digital+camera
```

Comment: Thanks. But I couldn't use this method on server without graphic support.

Comment: @c20ad4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff67 You don't *need* graphic support for this. I've done all this in the command line. Just add that header field to your request and those keywords will appear.

Comment: Thx. It works quite well even without firefox. Could you explain why you choose Mozilla/5.0?

Comment: @c20ad4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff67 I chose any random user agent. Note that a lot of browsers (including Safari), have "Mozilla" in their [full name user agent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Opera/). E.g: `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3` <- safari

Comment: @c20ad4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff67 No, because usually a [headless browser](http://blog.arhg.net/2009/10/what-is-headless-browser.html) interprets javascript too and might do other things too. Adding that user-agent header is merely a way of your script saying to amazon's webserver "Hi, I'm using this browser: Mozilla/5.0". The server does not know if you are lying or not. But a GUI is never used in this process. It is merely an identification string. In that sense, it is headless. Read up more about [user-agent spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_spoofing) on Wikipedia.